# Is there a way to ensure that an ASP.NET application is (only) running on the HTTPS protocol?

Tags: asp.net, http, iis, https

I'm wondering if there is a way to ensure that an ASP.NET application can only be run using the HTTPS protocol

I'm fine with any code (defensive programming measure perhaps?) that can do the trick, or possibly some IIS/web server setting that can get the job done.

Comment: In case you've missed my edit, there's also a defensive programming measure you can take. Request.IsSecureConnection

Comment: I caught it, thanks for the edit, that really ensures that the code base can only be executed on the https protocol.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

IIS will definitely allow you to require HTTPS. The instructions [are here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/324069).

**Edit:** I had to go dig for it, but there's also [Request.IsSecureConnection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.issecureconnection.aspx) for defensive programming.

Comment: FTA: 8. Click Require secure-channel (SSL) if you want the Web site, folder, or file to require SSL communications.

Answer (score 3):

The only problem with enforcing the SSL on the IIS level is that the user receives an ugly 403.4 page error

> "The page must be viewed over a secure channel"

To make the transition seamless, you could redirect the user to the secure site using the `Request.IsSecureConnection` if they do not generate the request over SSL.

Comment: There are basic network setups you can do to redirect to HTTPS before IIS ever sees the request.

Answer (score 1):

There is a nice [article](http://www.leastprivilege.com/PartiallySSLSecuredWebAppsWithASPNET.aspx) that has some good information and a helper utility class on this subject over at [leastprivilege.com](http://www.leastprivilege.com/)